# How can I use @ForeignKeys in same table in Room database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

Let me explain my problem. Here is my code in android studio:

```java
@Entity(tableName = "family_table",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Person.class,parentColumns = "myId",childColumns = "parentId"))
public class Person {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long myId;
    private long parentId;

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;


    public Person( String name, int age, String gender) {
        this.myId = IdGenerator.generate();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setMyId(long myId) {
        this.myId = myId;
    }
    public void setParentId(long parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getMyId() {
        return myId;
    }
    public long getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

Now I have created some entry in database as follow:

[image]

I want to use the `@ForeignKeys` annotation in the same table. As in the code I want to reference the `parentId` with the `myId` column. But the application crashed. Any suggestion?

Comment: I believe ForeignKey is something designed  to provide a link between data in two tables in any relational database. So I don't think you could do this for one table.
Could you be more specific why you wanted this?

Comment: I've seen in a youtube video that suggest foreign key can be used to reference the same table. I'm going to make a family hierarchy app. In which every entry is an object of Person.class. Every person have an ID(primary key) and a parentId. The parent Id is referenced to other person's ID. As every entry in my database is an object of Person.class. So it is reasonable to create only one table(which I named family_table). But I can't find any way to use reference inside same table. Can you give me any suggession?

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. And what is the reason for a crash? What does the logcat say?

Comment: I used long rather than Long. Now it works(see answer). By the way, Logcat said: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)`. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've done the constraint in right way. Sqlite (Room) allows to use self-referencing Foreign Key.

But I suppose you met with a problem while inserting first parent-rows with empty "parentId" (you use "0" for empty "parent id" but it should be set to "null" instead. Otherwise you'll get error about constraints violation).

Try to change type "Long" to your "parentId" instead of "long". That will allow to set null values to the field "parentId".